# Singular value decomposition of $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, singular-values

Let $c \in \mathbb C$ and

$$A_c:=\begin{pmatrix}1 && 0 \\ 1-c && c\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb C^{2\times2}$$

Does this work like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742651/2x2-fibonacci-matrix-singular-value-decomposition) but with $^*$ (adjugate) instead of $^T$ (transpose)? because our matrix is complex.

What do I have to do if $A_c$ is not a regular matrix?

$$W=A^*A=\begin{pmatrix}1&&1-\bar c\\0&&\bar c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&&0\\1-c&&c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1+(1-\bar c)(1-c)&&(1-\bar c)c\\\bar c(1-c)&&\bar c c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2+|c|^2-\bar c -c &&-|c|^2+c\\-|c|^2+\bar c&&|c|^2\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, using a computer algebra system I end up with the following eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of the matrix $W$ (eigenvalues on the left, eigenvectors on the right):
[image]

So, obviously I'm doing something wrong because $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ can't be an eigenvector

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly the same as in the link, and you indeed have to change the transpose by the complex adjugate.

If $A_c$ is singular, the calculation is still the same. In that case one of the eigenvalues of $A_c^* A_c$ will be zero, so the matrix $\Sigma$ will be of the form $\mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1, 0)$.

The only difference that I can think of is that you can't use an expression like $u_2 = \frac{1}{\sigma_2}A_c v_2$ when you want to calculate $u_2$, since $\sigma_2=0$. But you can find $u_2$ by taking a unit vector orthogonal to $u_1$.

Comment: Okay, in the task it says 'if $A_c$ is singular, first diagonalize the Matrix $A^*A$. The singular values of $A$ are the roots of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$'. Do you know what is meant by this? (I think my professor meant $A_c$ instead of $A$)

Comment: Even if $A_c$ is regular, you also first have to diagonalize the matrix $A^*_c A_c$, it does not matter whether $A_c$ is singular or not. And indeed it needs to say $A_c$ everytime instead of $A$. (I also forgot the subscript $c$ in my answer so I edited that as well.)

Comment: The only difference that I can think of is that it might be a little bit different to calculate the left singular vector $u_2$, since $\sigma_2 =0$, but this is not too difficult either. I added a few words in the answer.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look at the calculations tomorrow and see if I run into any problems

Comment: I tried doing it, but I was not sucessfull. I editet my question above. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: I can only acknowledge that $(0, 0)$ is not an eigenvector and that something went wrong. I've put the matrix in a CAS myself and found non-zero eigenvectors. But they look ugly. And doing the calculation by hand isn't a picnic either. I don't see any shortcut or alternative way to determine the SVD in a fast way.